# How to wait for response and resume work in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

My network connection drops for 10-60 seconds once every hour or so.

For diagnostics, I have found and adapted a batch script (**ping_log.bat**) that pings google.com every x seconds and saves the output to a text file. This tells me when the network interruptions happen.

How do I extend ping_log.bat so that it calls the **network_diagnostics.bat** file when a network timeout happens (ping command times out)? And returns to running normally after the timeout is over?

**ping_log.bat (based on a post on SO)**, The long one-liner is taken from [StackOverflow: Ping with timestamp on Windows CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24907186/764285):

```
@echo off
call network_diagnostics.bat REM this line needs to be called only when the ping command times out

ping -t www.google.com|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!time! !data!)&ping -n 2 www.google.com>nul" >> log.txt
```

How the output file looks:

```
13:43:34.96 Pinging www.google.com [142.250.74.35] with 32 bytes of data:
13:43:20.00 Reply from 142.250.74.35: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=52
13:43:25.07 Reply from 142.250.74.35: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=52
13:43:30.13 Reply from 142.250.74.35: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=52
13:43:35.20 Reply from 142.250.74.35: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=52
13:43:45.24 Request timed out.
13:43:50.31 Reply from 142.250.74.35: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=52
```

**network_diagnostics.bat**:

```
ipconfig /all

REM This file actually contains more, but in order to produce a Minimum Viable Code Example, I am showing only a single line here.
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking or what the problem is. If you want to limit the question asked, then this isn’t really about diagnosing your network connection at all, and is more of a question about batch programming. Please update your title and refine your question so it’s clear what you are trying to do and what’s not working or what’s happening instead. Post all the code and clearly specify exactly what you want to happen. As it is you’ve mentioned network problems, logging problems, ping output to a single line, and calling other batch script problems.

Comment: Alright, after waking up and seeing this, it looks worse than when I posted it. My fault. I will improve the question when I get back home, and limit it to calling a second batch file.